# Apple-documented, low-level, userland API for iOS

Tags: ios, low-level

What is the equivalent of Win32's **Kernel32** on iOS?

Otherwise put: What is the lowest-level, fully-documented (by Apple), stable, supported, userland API on iOS for things like:

- Managing memory
- Async file I/O
- Thread management
- Wrappers for synchronization primitives & concurrency constructs

So far what I have found has been a mix of a externally-documented mach and BSD API's together miscellaneous headers (OSMalloc.h, for example). Additionally, the link Apple provides on it's *Kernel Programming Guide* to the "Up-to-date versions of the Mach 3 APIs" is dead

Comment: Care to explain reason for downvote?

Comment: ***"Use your downvotes whenever you encounter an egregiously sloppy, no-effort-expended post, or an answer that is clearly and perhaps dangerously incorrect."***  ; I believe the question is well-formed, and I've clearly tried, reading the platform guides, and researching externally-documented API's.

Comment: I didn't down vote, but perhaps your question is a little broad.  You don't say what you are actually trying to achieve and I suspect that most iOS programmers don't really think in the way that you are asking your question.  For file io you would typically use `NSInputStream` and `NSOutputStream` but at a lower level you have `fopen` and friends as on any UNIX-like system. For threading, synchronisation and concurrency, Grand Central Dispatch. For memory management, I am not sure...Objective C or Swift handle it automatically for the most part. You have malloc in Objective C

Comment: @Paulw11 Thank you for your response. GCD, malloc, ect are still all high-level constructs - mach implements all the virtual memory management (vm_allocate(), ect) and kernel threads. I don't know about fopen; BSD implements the filesystem management as far as I can tell, you're probably right to think fopen just a wrapper around the system call (unlike Windows, in which C std lib functions like this are very high level). I was really, really hoping for a central, documented API for XNU (mach + BSD + I/O Kit) supported by Apple.

Comment: I know that Apple strongly recommends that you use GCD for threading on both iOS and OS X but Posix threads are available. This is the lowest level threading API that you would use on a UNIX system

Comment: @Paulw11 Ya I'm not saying GCD is a bad API - I like it a lot actually. pthreads are wrappers around mach threads in iOS/OS X btw - they are what the mach kernel actually deals with.

Answer (score 1):

Start with [Apple's opensource XNU project](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/xnu/xnu-3248.20.55/). Look to use:

**[mach](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/xnu/xnu-3248.20.55/osfmk/mach/mach_traps.h)** ([impl](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/xnu/xnu-3248.20.55/libsyscall/mach/))

- Thread management
- IPC
- Virtual memory
- Concurrency constructs
- Timing

**[BSD](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/xnu/xnu-3248.20.55/bsd/kern/syscalls.master)**

- POSIX implementation
- GCD
- Async file IO via kqueue/kevent
- Networking

**[Clang language extensions](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/LanguageExtensions.html)**

- Wrappers for ldrex, ldaex, strex, stlex, clrex, dmb, dsb, isb